# Calculate Running Average of Undetermined Length for Sensor

Tags: javascript, average

I am trying to calculate the running average of a value returned by a sensor and run a command when the average value meets two criteria (array.length == x && avg < y).

```
let arr = []
let avg = 0
let sum = 0

sensor.calibrate(() => {
  sensor.getMeasurement((volts) => {
    console.log(volts) // typical values are ~0.9 V
    runningAvg(volts, 0.85, 10)
  })
})

function runningAvg(item, threshold, length) {
  if (array.length < length) {
    array.push(item)
  } else {
    array.shift().push(item)
    for(let i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
      sum += array[i]
    }
    avg = sum / length
  }
  if(avg < threshold && array.length == length) console.log(avg)
}
```

This code returned 0.

How can I calculate the running average and run a bit of code when the average is < threshold and array.length == length?

Comment: I think that this line `array.shift().push(item)` should throw an exception, because `shift()` returns a single item. Doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. Thank you!!